# Не выполняется условие if

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, if

Есть метод

```
@RequestMapping(value = "updateEquip", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView updateEquipment(@ModelAttribute("equipment") Equipment equipment, BindingResult result) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        user = userService.findByUserName(equipment.getUser().getUsername());
        equipment.setUser(user);
        equipmentService.update(equipment);
        model.addObject("allEquip", equipmentService.getAllEquipments());
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String name = auth.getName();
        User user = userService.findByName(name);
        Set<UserRole> allRoles = user.getUserRole();
        for (UserRole userRole : allRoles) {
            authRole = userRole.getRole();
        }
        if (authRole == "ROLE_ADMIN") {
            model.setViewName("redirect: superAdmin");
        } else if (authRole == "ROLE_ACCAUNT") {
            model.setViewName("redirect: accaunt");
        }else {
            model.setViewName("redirect: login");
        }
        return model;
    }
```

Если отдельно отправляю `authRole` на страницу, то значение правильно выводится в зависимости от роли. А в этом методе условие не работает, при любой авторизации, он переходит на страницу `login`.

Почему он не переходит на страницу, если выполняется условие?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не правильно сравниваете строки.

`==` сравнивает ссылки, а именно указывают ли они на **один и тот же объект**.

Вам следует использовать метод `equals`, который сравнивает объекты основываясь на их содержании.

Comment: Спасибо. Вы правы. А то второй день не мог понять проблему.